# Tempered distribution and Sobolev spaces

Tags: sobolev-spaces, distribution-theory

The Schwartz space $\mathcal S(\mathbb R^d)$ is the set of all complex-valued function $f \in C^{\infty}(\mathbb R^d)$ such that $\sup_{x\in \mathbb R^d}|x^{\alpha}D^{\beta}f(x)|<\infty$ where $\alpha , \beta \in \mathbb N_{0}^{d}, D^{\beta}=\frac{\partial^{|\beta|}}{\partial^{\beta_{1}} ...\partial^{\beta_{d}}},|\beta|=\beta_{1}+ ... +\beta_{d} $.

$\mathcal S'(\mathbb R^d)$ is the collection of all complex-valued linear continuous functions over $\mathcal S(\mathbb R^d)$ (tempered distribution).

Sobolev space $H^{s}(\mathbb R^d)=\left\{f\in \mathcal S'(\mathbb R^d): (1+|x|^{2})^{\frac{s}{2}}\hat{f}\in L^{2}(\mathbb R^d)\right\}, s\in \mathbb R$, where $\hat{f}$ is the fourier transform of f.

My question is f is in $H^{1}(\mathbb R)$ if and only if it is a tempered distribution such as $\hat{f}(1+|xi|)$ belongs to $L^{2}$.

Answer (score 0):

First a comment on the definition you provide. Explicitly, the the definition is that $f$ is in $H^1$ if and only if all of the following conditions hold true:

1. $f$ is a tempered distribution, $f\in\mathcal S'$
2. The Fourier transform of $f$ is a function, $\hat f\in L^1_{\mbox{loc}}$
3. The Fourier transform is in a certain weighted $L^2$ space, $(1+|x|^2)^{1/2}\hat f\in L^2$

Again, let me stress the fact that the condition $(1+|x|^2)^{1/2}\hat f\in L^2$ requires $f$ to be a function!

Observe now that $(1+|x|^2)^{1/2}\leq 1+|xi| \leq 2^{1/2}(1+|x|^2)^{1/2}$. It follows for any measurable function $\hat f$ that
$$
(1+|x|^2)^{1/2}|\hat f|\leq ´(1+|xi|)|\hat f| \leq 2^{1/2}(1+|x|^2)^{1/2}|\hat f|.
$$

The point of this computation is that if $f$ is a distribution such that condition 1 and 2 above hold, then condition $3$ is equivalent to the condition

$\hspace{0.1cm}$ 3'. The Fourier transform is in a certain weighted $L^2$ space, $(1+|xi|)\hat f\in L^2$

Comment: I'm not clear. Can you provide me more detail advise?

Comment: I understand your computation, but I want to know clearly the purpose of this computation. What will we get after that?

Comment: I want to ask you more that since $H^{s}(\mathbb R^d)\subset \mathcal S'(\mathbb R^d)$, can we conclude that if $f \in H^{1}(\mathbb R)$, it is a tempered distribution with the same condition I asked above?

Comment: I've tried to flesh out my answer a bit. The answer to your last question is yes. By the way, are you sure you mean to write $|xi|$, with $i$ denoting the imaginary unit?

Comment: No, xi is here the variable. Now, I understand your process, but I want to know clearly that why condition 2 is necessary for condition 3 equivalent to 3'? because $\hat{f}$ is measurable?

Comment: And the three conditions above are true in general or we need to prove?

Comment: In general you have to prove that all three conditions are met. Condition 2 is a prerequisite for both 3 and 3', in the sense that both conditions implicitly assume condition 2 to be met.